# CoreDNS: How Cache entry gets added after Forward plugin

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, coredns

Trying to understand code flow. Plugin order seems to be: https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/plugin.cfg

So its Cache much before Forward. If there is a Cache miss, but Forward returns a successful DNS reply, where in the code do we add a Cache entry - wondering since Cache plugin runs before Forward.

I see in Cache plugin: [CoreDNS](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/38d4dacb887579b6e241b97e22f9066ac8c6f6d6/plugin/cache/handler.go#L43)

```
// ServeDNS implements the plugin.Handler interface.
func (c *Cache) ServeDNS(ctx context.Context, w dns.ResponseWriter, r *dns.Msg) (int, error)
 // getIgnoreTTL unconditionally returns an item if it exists in the cache.
 i := c.getIgnoreTTL(now, state, server)
 if i == nil {
        // cache miss
        crr := &ResponseWriter{ResponseWriter: w, Cache: c, state: state, server: server, do: do}
        return c.doRefresh(ctx, state, crr)
    }
```

I guess ResponseWriter will not add any entry in Cache as Forward has not been called yet - is this correct?
In forwarder plugin, I do not see any call to add the DNS response/result entry in cache. How does cache get populated after Primary Forward resolves a DNS request?

Answer (score 0):

In plugin/cache/[cache.go](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/plugin/cache/cache.go#L145),

```
func (w *ResponseWriter) WriteMsg(res *dns.Msg) error {}
```

"rewrites" `dns.ResponseWriter`'s `WriteMsg()`, so in `forward.go`, [when it calls `w.WriteMsg(ret)`](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/plugin/forward/forward.go#L180), the result will be written to cache (through the overwritten `WriteMsg()` by cache plugin).

As in doRefresh(), it passes in *ResponseWriter rather than the *dns.ResponseWriter: https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/plugin/cache/handler.go#L73